# Peer review processes for company shareholders

Tags: performance-reviews

I'm one of five shareholders in our company (all shares are split evenly between us). When we decide to pay out dividends, instead of doing a payout directly proportional to our shares in the company (i.e. everyone gets the same amount), we would like to determine the percentages for each shareholder by using a combination of performance metrics (like actual time worked, work performance, a baseline amount just for being a shareholder, etc.) and compare results relative to each other.

There are more complex details to the whole idea so I won't explain it here. We are well aware of the potential negative and positive tradeoffs (like people being unhappy if they are rated lower than their personal impression of themselves). Needless to say we have all discussed it in great depth and are in full agreement to proceed with it.

The crucial part that is still missing is how to evaluate work performance. For various reasons we can't apply objective metrics to work performance (or to put it another way 'importance to the various projects each of us worked on'). For example, there are artists involved and rating their contribution can only be done on a subjective basis.

For this reason we want to apply some form of peer review process. What formal peer review processes, or concrete examples of peer review processes used in real world companies are there?

Comment: Requests for lists of examples are notoriously difficult be on-topic on stackexchange sites since it is unlikely that there could ever be a correct answer.  Realistically, though, it probably makes sense to come up with something that seems fair to you rather than trying to adapt procedures from other companies.  It is unlikely, for example, that the way that Amazon does 360 degree reviews is going to be of much help to a very small company.

Comment: This is going to end in tears.

Comment: why not pay those who work in the company a salary in the usual way, and make dividends go only to shareholders, also in the usual way? Why have a complicated dividend and try to entirely re-invent all the concepts of compensation?

Comment: Um a company is a collective  dividends should be distributed to the owners according to the number of shares.

Imagine what would happen if Google started giving some share holders more dividends  the FCC would crucify them

Comment: By law (at least in the US) the shares of a company entitle you to a percentage of the profits regardless of how much effort you put in them. If you want to reward people based on performance metrics, pay them a salary or wage, deduct it from the profit, then split the profit at the end by percentage. What you are proposing sounds like a lawsuit waiting to happen (and which the others will probably lose).

Comment: This is going to get messy and bitter, pretty quickly I would imagine.

Comment: "*how to evaluate work performance*" Perform the arcane art of "Managing". Having decent managers would help. Things that do not help: people suggesting dumb ideas like evaluating performance when there is no existing performance rating framework in place, outsourcing your management work to the internet, or throwing words like "dividend" around without knowing what they mean.

Comment: @RonBeyer that's the start of a good answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @everyone Please do not go off topic. I have not asked whether or not this is a good idea. And please do not lecture me on any law implications, we have obviously considered this and made sure what we want to do is actually legal (also we're not based in the U.S.)

Comment: @TravisG Not sure its off-topic to mention the legal side, dividends means a portion of the profit by ownership % by definition, what you are asking (incorrectly using the word dividend) is about either a performance bonus, salary, or other wage. Unless you have different levels of stock, you have to distribute it equally if you are calling it a *dividend*. What you want to do is *legal* but somebody hurt about a lower share is going to cause you a lot of trouble, even if its just terminology.

Comment: I think your real question here is, "how to setup a performance evaluation framework when performance cannot be evaluated objectively?" I understand that you were led to the question by your requirement to give out dividends based on performance, but that is an independent point altogether. You might want to edit the question to focus only on the performance evaluation framework part of it. What you do with the framework is entirely up to you.

Comment: @MaskedMan Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

> What formal peer review processes, or concrete examples of peer review
>   processes used in real world companies are there?

I knew of one small high-tech company that divided up a significant bonus pool during an open year-end review session that lasted a 3-day weekend.

If I remember correctly, they all gathered offsite, went over the significant events from the year, went over all the numbers for sales, new customers, etc, and then discussed bonus allocations.

I believe they started with the premise that everyone gets an equal bonus, and then each person in turn talked about the accomplishments of the others (not themselves), and put in a "pitch" for why others should get more than an equal share.

Presumably, at the end of the weekend, people would end up with unequal shares - based on how much they contributed to the success of the company over the preceding year, as judged by everyone else.

I remember that they were quite pleased with the results of the process the first two years. I sort of lost direct contact after that, but I heard through the grapevine that it didn't go quite as well in subsequent years. I don't know the details, other than the fact that some partners felt cheated.

This isn't something I would ever advocate for, but I suppose it could work.

Comment: You have a lot more faith than I do Joe

Comment: *but I suppose it could work* - Personally I would never suppose that - so I guess that is where your extra dash of faith comes in !!!